# 'If' in Regex Expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

Sentence can be either of followings:

```
Any1?Any2 (e.g  'geg f834&%uh3?us7 G&^gb')
```

or

```
Any (e.g  'geg f834&%')
```

I need to take them in 2 variables, A and B, that is A is for former, B is for latter, dividing by question mark.

So, in first case, A should be `geg f834&%uh3` and B should be `us7 G&^gb`.
In 2nd case, A should be `geg f834&%` and B should be empty string.

I want just one regex expression to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For your example strings, you could match "Any" by matching not a question mark  using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and make the following question mark optional to capture 2 groups.

With 2 matches you get 2 groups:

[`([^?]+)\??([^?]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/yFko4L/1)

With 1 match you get 2 groups where the second group will be empty:

[`([^?]+)\??([^?]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/uzp319/1)

**Explanation**

- `([^?]+)` Match not a question mark one or more times and capture in group 1
- `\??` Match optional question mark
- `([^?]*)` Match not a question mark zero or more times and capture in group 2

Comment: @Davis Herring When the second string is empty and there is a delimiter there will be an empty capturing group. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Davis Herring The Op is looking for 2 variables. When there is a delimiter there will be 2 groups containing the values. When there is no delimiter the second group will be empty. So the distinguish part is in the value of the second group.

Comment: But “a?” and “a” give the same results: the second group matches (and is empty) _despite_ having no delimiter at all.

Comment: Upon rereading the question, I realize that it allows this lack of specificity, so it’s not a fair criticism.  But what I was trying to get at is that `([^?]+)(?:\?([^?]*))` is superior in that it allows detecting the delimiter’s presence even as the last character—the second group doesn’t match, even as the empty string, if there’s no delimiter.

Comment: @Davis Herring I think that that is what this question is about. If there is no part after the ? or no ? at all,  there should be an empty second group. Then programmatically you could create a variabe A for group 1 and a variable B with an  empty string.

Comment: Yes: I’m just trying to answer a question more broadly useful than was asked.

Answer (score 0):

For constructing conditional regular expression, you can use `(?ifthen|else)`. For the `if` part you can use  [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `if` for that. The regular expression is:

```
/(.*)\?(.*)/
```

Now, whether your second match will be an "empty string" or e.g. `undefined`/`null`/etc., or if it matters which of these it is, depends on what language you are using.

Comment: Nice and simple but you won't get any match for case 2

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should give you what you need

```
([^?]+)(?:\?)?(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/6s7IJI/1